# Replace cyrilic symbols in Nlog output

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, nlog, transliteration, kestrel

Running asp.net core application using kestrel on Linux machine. SSH Console output looks weird if a line contains Cyrillic symbols. Is there any way to configure nlog to replace Cyrillic symbols with [translit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_romanizations_of_Cyrillic#Translit)?
Example of a bad output

```
 06.05.2020 09:57:11.650||TRACE||<<Session:831259AB-493A-4215-89BB-81FF8802C714||Node:[[7_11 ▒вод индек▒а ▒ег▒л▒▒ной до▒▒авки]]||Phone:  >>
```

Nlog target:

```
<target name="Console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false" layout="============================================================================================${newline} ${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff}||${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}||&lt;&lt;Session:${pad:padding=36:inner=${event-properties:item=sessionId:uppercase=true}}||Node:[[${event-properties:item=nodename}]]||Phone:${pad:padding=13:inner=${event-properties:item=number:uppercase=true}}>>${newline} ${message}" >
```

If there is a way to display Cyrillic symbol correctly without making changes to Linux configuration, that will be acceptable.

[image]

Comment: No idea what targets you are using but both Console-Target and File-Target has Encoding-option. Try changing it to UTF8

Comment: Here`s my target:

    <target name="Console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false"
      layout="============================================================================================${newline}
${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff}||${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}||&lt;&lt;Session:${pad:padding=36:inner=${event-properties:item=sessionId:uppercase=true}}||Node:[[${event-properties:item=nodename}]]||Phone:${pad:padding=13:inner=${event-properties:item=number:uppercase=true}}>>${newline}
      ${message}" >

Comment: Better to update your question with extra detail, than writing it in comments (General rule on StackOverflow). And what happens when you use `Encoding="UTF-8"` ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported out of the box as transliteration is also not supported out of the box in .NET.

But luckily you could add this without much hassle.

I'm using the NuGet package [NickBuhro.Translit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NickBuhro.Translit/)

> Install-Package NickBuhro.Translit

And add this layout renderer wrapper

```cs
using System;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers;
using NickBuhro.Translit;

namespace MyExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Translit to latin. Usage: ${translit:${message}} or ${message:translit=true}
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutRenderer("translit")]
    [AmbientProperty("translit")]
    [ThreadAgnostic]
    [ThreadSafe]
    public class TranslitLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
    {
        protected override string Transform(string text)
        {
            var latin = Transliteration.CyrillicToLatin(text, Language.Russian);
            return latin;
        }
    }
}
```

and register as soon as possible, e.g. in the main() before NLog starts (be aware of static fields)

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
    s.RegisterLayoutRenderer<TranslitLayoutRendererWrapper>("translit")
);
```

And now you could use  `${translit:${message}}` or `${message:translit=true}`